# Google FastButton Multiple Use

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I've implemented the Google FastButton script into a web page.  Following:

[Trying to implement Google's Fast Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300136/trying-to-implement-googles-fast-button)

The code works great.  My question is how do I implement this for multiple buttons.  I have several buttons that are dynamically created. I don't want to define each button with its own function.  Can I use this script with another function that passes some variable.

For example, `<button id="quick" onclick="someFunction(24);">button</button>`

Current implementation

```
new FastButton(document.getElementById('quick'), function() {
       alert("hello");
    });
<button onclick="onLayerClick(8)">8</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it: According to the link you pasted, the FastButton prototype accepts a function as its second argument (`this.FastButton = function(element, handler)`) and passes the click event to that function. So if you do something like this:

HTML:

```
<button id="quick">24</button>
```

JS:

```
var myHandler = function(event) {
    var el = event.target;
    console.log(el.innerHTML);
}

new FastButton(document.getElementById('quick'), myHandler);
```

Then the `myHandler()` function will have access to the DOM element where the click event originated (`event.target`), which will be whatever button was clicked. So you'll have access to that button's innerHTML, or you could put a `data-mynumber="24"` attribute on the button and use `el.getAttribute("data-mynumber")` instead of `el.innerHTML`... However you want to identify the button is up to you.

Comment: Your logic seems to work for the first element.  But then every element after that with the id "quick" doesn't work.  How can I apply this to every id or class with "quick"

Comment: You can't have more than one DOM element with the same id. If you instead use a class, you can do something like this (assuming jQuery): `$(".quick").each(function() { new FastButton(this, myHandler); });`

Comment: I'm using javascript.  How would I do it with standard js

Comment: `var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("quick"); for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) { new FastButton(buttons[i], myHandler); }` is one way